# How to use intersect() function with date ranges in R

Tags: r

Here is my code:

```
a<-"2015-12-13 09:00:00"           
b<-"2015-12-13 12:00:00"
c<-interval(a,b)

d<-"2015-12-13 09:00:00"           
e<-"2015-12-13 12:00:00"
f<-interval(d,e)
h<-intersect(c,f)
h
```

The values of `c`,`f` and `h` are:

```
> h
[1] 10800
> c
[1] 2015-12-13 09:00:00 UTC--2015-12-13 12:00:00 UTC
> f
[1] 2015-12-13 09:00:00 UTC--2015-12-13 12:00:00 UTC
>
```

But, when I give a different date/time range. The intersect function does not work. For example:
If I change the time of the variable d and e from `09:00:00-12:00:00` to `09:00:00 - 10:00:00`, I am expecting the `intersect` function to give me the minutes for 1 hour that is common.

```
a<-"2015-12-13 09:00:00"           
b<-"2015-12-13 12:00:00"
c<-interval(a,b)

d<-"2015-12-13 09:00:00"           
e<-"2015-12-13 10:00:00"
f<-interval(d,e)
h<-intersect(c,f)
h
```

Output:

```
numeric(0)
> c
[1] 2015-12-13 09:00:00 UTC--2015-12-13 12:00:00 UTC
> f
[1] 2015-12-13 09:00:00 UTC--2015-12-13 10:00:00 UTC
```

I get numeric(0). Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: where does your function `interval`comes from? If you call `library(lubridate)` before your code, all works fine ...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried calling library(lubridate) before my code. But it didn't help. Could you please help. Please see my full code below.                                                                                                           library(lubridate)
a<-"2015-12-13 11:00:00" 
b<-"2015-12-13 12:00:00"
c<-interval(a,b)

d<-"2015-12-13 11:00:00" 
e<-"2015-12-13 13:00:00"
f<-interval(d,e)
h<-intersect(f,c)
c
f
h

Comment: With R 3.3.1 and lubridate 1.6.0 this is not reproducible. I get this output, see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg9N0.jpg

Comment: Thanks! It works when I use the package lubridate. But, there is a requirement that I have to use the intersect() along with another package "dplyr". The intersect() doesn't work when I am using the package dplyr

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of avoiding answering in the comments:

As [J_F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6045390/j-f) mentions above, you need to use the `intersect` function from `lubridate`. In case you face problems because you need `intersect` from  both `lubridate` and `dplyr` you can use the double colon `::`.

Double colon `::` is used to specify from which package you call a function and overcomes masking. So in your code:

```
a<-"2015-12-13 09:00:00"           
b<-"2015-12-13 12:00:00"
c<-interval(a,b)

d<-"2015-12-13 09:00:00"           
e<-"2015-12-13 10:00:00"
f<-interval(d,e)
h<-lubridate::intersect(c,f)
h

[1] 2015-12-13 09:00:00 UTC--2015-12-13 10:00:00 UTC
```